# How can I commit generated files on schedule using Github-actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have written a web scraping application in R, which scrapes the headline links on the homepage of a news website, and I want to run it on schedule, with intervals of 20 minutes every day, using Github-Actions. I believe I have set up my YAML file correctly, and have also included my R script in the repo.
Please see below my YAML file:

```
name: Aljazeera_headlines_scraper

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '*/20 * * * 1-5'


jobs: 
  autoscrape:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: windows-latest

    # Load repo and install R
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master

    # Set-up R
    - name: Install packages
      run: |
        R -e 'install.packages("rvest")'
        R -e 'install.packages("tidyverse")'
    # Run R script
    - name: Scrape
      run: Rscript Aljazeera_scraper.R
      
 # Add new files in data folder, commit along with other modified files, push
    - name: Commit files
      run: |
        git config --local user.name actions-user
        git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
        git add data/*
        git commit -am "GH ACTION Headlines $(date)"
        git push origin main
      env:
        REPO_KEY: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        username: github-actions
```

Also, here is the web scraping script:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

aljurl <- read_html(paste0("https://www.aljazeera.com/"))

headlinks <- aljurl %>% 
  html_nodes(".u-clickable-card__link") %>% 
  html_attr("href")

links <- data.frame(
  date = Sys.Date(),
  headline_links = headlinks
)

write.csv(links,file = paste0("Headlinks.csv"),append = TRUE)
```

I want to update a `.csv` file every time the application runs. However, I keep getting a workflow failure report in Github-Actions. I do not know what I am not doing right. Please, I would greatly appreciate your helpful suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: We need more details on the "workflow failure report"

Comment: Hi, I get this error message in the log:

"Run git config --local user.name actions-user
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
 Headlinks.csv

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
Error: Process completed with exit code 1."

Comment: The error you’re seeing is completely unrelated to R. The step that’s failing is the commit step (and in fact data *was* generated by the R script, as the error message indicates). You seem to have checked out a different branch, not `main`. Or maybe you haven’t checked out a branch at all.

Comment: I think the error is related to where you are saving the csv file. You are saving it to `Headlines.csv`, but you are trying to add files from `data/*` to git. I suppose you want to change `"Headlinks.csv"` to `"data/Headlinks.csv"`. Also, you don't need `paste0`.

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience caused, but I am getting this new error message, after making the aforementioned changes to the ` data/Headlinks.csv. ` 

" Run git config --local user.name actions-user
[main 8417ec0] GH ACTION Headlines Wed Dec  1 14:11:55 UTC 2021
 1 file changed, 40 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 rewrite data/Headlinks.csv (100%)
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Ifeanyi55/AutoRun'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1. "

Comment: Is it a public or a private repo? If you could share it, will could try to help you resolve your issue, reproducing it in a fork 

Comment: Here is the link to the repo

https://github.com/Ifeanyi55/AutoScraper.git

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar. I'd recommend you check out https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-commit

For my own use case, here's what I did :

1. I set up my GitHub action to run on a daily schedule to generate a CSV file from the Postgres client (`psql`) or a scraper
2. After generating the CSV file on the job, I use `EndBug/add-and-commit@v9` GitHub actions to commit and push it to my repository

Obviously, in your case, you would just have to replace the job step from "Generate CSV" to your own job

For reference:

- [Workflow example 1](https://github.com/ngshiheng/michelin-my-maps/blob/ea28f7599d2f658d2b97963a0ce9d696f4d39d73/.github/workflows/scrape.yml#L32)
- [Workflow example 2](https://github.com/ngshiheng/michelin-my-maps/blob/ea28f7599d2f658d2b97963a0ce9d696f4d39d73/.github/workflows/scrape.yml#L32)